# Find points of intersection for the functions: $f(x)=3x-5$ and $G(x)=-4x+9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried the algebraic method: 
$$3 \cdot x-5 =-4 \cdot x+9 $$
      -9.       -9
$$3 \cdot x-14=-4 \cdot x$$
+4x.      +4x 
$$3 \cdot x-14 = 0$$

$\quad$But I'm sure I did something wrong along the way and I'm not sure where to go from here,
if i did do nothing wrong.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math SE! your equations are not easily readable. Would you mind please repeating what you tried, but put every equation in between dollar signs? this will turn f(x)=3x-5 to $f(x)=3x-5$.

Comment: You'll enjoy this wonderful tutorial, [how to write formula on StackOver.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: In your final step, you did not add $4x$ to the left hand side.

Comment: What does $-9,-9$ and $+4x, +4x$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

I know that your question very easy, but I will help you
$$3x-5=-4x+9$$
add $4x$ for both sides
$$3x-5+4x=-4x+9+4x$$
$$7x-5=9$$
add 5 for both sides
$$7x-5+5=9+5$$
$$7x=14$$
divide by 7
$$\frac{7}{7}x=\frac{17}{7}$$
$$x=2$$

Comment: Then,  
\begin{align}
f(x) &= 3 \cdot x  - 5, \text{ for $x=2$} \\
f(2) &= 3 \cdot 2 - 5 = 1
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

> Using graphic method: http://desmos.com

[image]

### Bibliography:

http://geogebra.org
http://mathstud.io/

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Essam has showed $x=2$ but you'll need the co-ordinates! (Plug into both functions to check!)